# qBittorrent randomly shuts down?

Tags: qbittorrent

Ubuntu 14.04

I have qBittorrent installed but it is randomly closing after a few minutes. There is no error message or anything so I am not sure why it is behaving like this.

I am just begining to learn about Linux/Ubuntu so as yet I don't know much about it.

Edit:
Just ran it through the terminal and got the following:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast


*************************************************************
Catching SIGABRT, please report a bug at http://bug.qbittorrent.org
and provide the following backtrace:
qBittorrent version: v3.1.8
stack trace:
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : gsignal()+0x39  [0x7fb15f1caf79]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : abort()+0x148  [0x7fb15f1ce388]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 : __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+0x155  [0x7fb15fad66b5]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 : ()+0x5e836  [0x7fb15fad4836]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 : ()+0x5e863  [0x7fb15fad4863]
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 : ()+0x5eaa2  [0x7fb15fad4aa2]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : ()+0xa74af  [0x7fb161be34af]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : boost::asio::ip::address::to_v4() const+0x28  [0x7fb161bfabc8]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : libtorrent::socks5_stream::socks_connect(boost::shared_ptr<boost::function<void (boost::system::error_code const&)> >)+0x7dd  [0x7fb161d34ebd]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : libtorrent::socks5_stream::connected(boost::system::error_code const&, boost::shared_ptr<boost::function<void (boost::system::error_code const&)> >)+0x1b1  [0x7fb161d35f41]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : ()+0x1fd6f5  [0x7fb161d396f5]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&)+0x29b  [0x7fb161bfa97b]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&)+0xe1  [0x7fb161bfea31]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : libtorrent::aux::session_impl::main_thread()+0x3c  [0x7fb161d158bc]
  /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7 : boost_asio_detail_posix_thread_function()+0xf  [0x7fb161bf327f]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 : ()+0x8182  [0x7fb161722182]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : clone()+0x6d  [0x7fb15f28f30d]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Start it from command line and check if it shows an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have toggled with the download options, limiting the amount of downloads and uploads allowed to run at the same time. I have also unchecked the 'use proxy for peer connections' box.

This seems to have solved the problem.